# Virtual server isn't working if I use www instead of just the domain

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

I have two domains. `Domain1` uses `IP1`, and `Domain2` uses `IP2`, however they both point at the same VPS.

I got it working if I go to `domain1.com`, however going to `www.domain1.com` gets stuck on the loading screen and ultimately says `Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.domain1.com!`. It does this in Firefox and IE as well.

While it's loading, it says `Resolving Host` at the bottom of my screen (in firefox, it says `Looking Up www.Domain1.com`).

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-7) tutorial to the letter. Basically:

1) Make a `public_html` directory

2) Run chmod to give 755 perms

3) Create an index file

4) Run command `cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain1.com`

5) Use nano to edit said file

6) Make this the file:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html 
</VirtualHost>`

7) Run `a2ensite domain1.com`

8) Restart apache

Comment: Do you have a DNS record for `www` that points to the correct ip address?

Comment: @joeqwerty Oh my god... This is what I get for staying up for two days straight. I updated the nameservers to point at through my registrar but didn't update my nameservers. Whoops. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with your DNS entry. Make sure you have an entry for the sub-domain(www) and the it points to domain1.com.